# System of second degree equations in 2 variables

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I have the following system:
$$\begin{cases} ax^2-2x+y^2-2=0 \\ -3x^2+x-2y+2=0 \end{cases}$$

I need to find all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ for which the system above has 2 real solutions. The problem also asks me to solve the system for $a=1$. It looks like the system has 2 real solutions and 2 complex solutions for $a=1$.

Substituting the $y$ from the second equation into the first one leads to a 4th degree polynomial which I can't seem to be able to solve.

I also tried completing squares in a bunch of ways with no succes.

I have noticed that the $x$ terms from the second equation can be written as $-3x^2+x-2=-(3x+2)(x-1)$. I doubt this can be used in any meaningful way.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: At least two real solutions or exactly two real solutions?  It seems like every value of $a$ gives at least two real solutions.

Comment: Applying Descartes Rules to the 4th degree polynomial that Dietrich Burde found in the answer below seems to indeed lead to your conclusion. The problem doesnt specify it though.

Comment: The polynomial takes the value $-4$ at $x=0$ and goes to $\infty$ at $\pm\infty$  If the problem doesn't specify, I would take it to mean "at least", but then the problem is a bit odd, because $a$ doesn't seem to play any role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $y=\frac{1}{2}(-3x^2+x+2)$ by the second equation. Then the first equation is
$$
4ax^2 + 9x^4 - 6x^3 - 11x^2 - 4x - 4=0
$$
For $a=1$ this equation has two complex solutions and two real solutions - as you said. In general, for a polynomial, we can use the rule of Descartes and others.

References:

[Number of real roots of a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780189/number-of-real-roots-of-a-polynomial)

Comment: Thanks. I have managed to apply Descartes and apparently the system has at least 2 real solutions for any real a.